# Symfony 3 and Doctrine relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, foreign-key-relationship, many-to-one, symfony-3.2

I am having two entities A and B. Let's say entity A has a primary key 'foo' and the entity B has a variable named 'bar'. I am trying to establish the "Many to one" association between these two. And when i run "update schema" command on my terminal, it is giving me this result:

> "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata."

here's the code:

```
class A
{
    /**
    * @var int
    * @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="bar")
    */
    private $foo;
}
```

and

```
class B
{
     /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="foo")
     */
     private $bar;
}
```

Comment: check the  `@ORM\Entity`  annotation is present in the class files

Comment: changes in annotations require clear:cache

Answer (score 0):

I think the   * @ORM\Entity is missing

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; 
instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the questioner.